# What is the correct way to get a byte array from a FileStream?

Tags: c#, .net

The [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) website has the code snippet:

```
  using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        // Read the source file into a byte array.
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fsSource.Length];
        int numBytesToRead = (int)fsSource.Length;
        int numBytesRead = 0;
        while (numBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
            int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

            // Break when the end of the file is reached.
            if (n == 0)
                break;

            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        }
    }
```

What concerns me is that `fsSource.Length` is a `long`, whereas `numBytesRead` is an `int` so at most only `2 * int.MaxValue` can be read into `bytes` (the head and the tail of the stream). So my questions are:

1. Is there some reason that this is OK?
2. If not, how should you read a `FileStream` into a `byte[]`.

Comment: `int.MaxValue` is 2GB. If you haven't already given special consideration to the fact that you are proposing to load more than 4GB of data into memory all at once, please do so now.

Comment: @B Tyler, @Jon: The Microsoft CLR has a 2GB max object size limit, so you're never going to be able to put more than `int.MaxValue` bytes in there however you read it. (Other platforms, like Mono, might not have that restriction.)

Comment: @Jon - So that would come under 1. then? There's no need to be like that about it, it is a valid question; your's is a valid answer, it's just not phrased very nicely.

Comment: @B Tyler: It was just a factual comment. Apologies if it (unintentionally) sounded rude, although it doesn't read like that to me.

Comment: @LukeH - not you, I thought your comment was spot on, thanks: it was a race condition.

Comment: @BTyler: Apologies from me as well -- certainly I didn't mean to be rude. It's just that your casual mention of `2 * int.MaxValue` made alarm bells ring in my head. Luke's comment is IMHO a "harder" argument against reading all of the file contents, so I don't have anything to add.

Comment: @Jon - thanks, much appreciated. For some reason I have the idea that `int` = small in my head. I don't any longer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation I wouldn't even bother processing the `FileStream` manually; use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) instead:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathSource);
```

Comment: One downside here is that if the file is really _that_ long for the original question to be a highlighted concern, then this does not facilitate the programmer to implement 'message pumping' / cancellation etc from the executing thread, through a long blocking call.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Very true. I was actually going to edit my answer to mention that, but got distracted. It's also possible in that situation that the OP might still want to read the entire stream, but buffer it into multiple `byte[]` arrays, or a composite collection of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

1. The sample code is good for most of applications where we are not reaching extremes.
2. If you have really long stream like say a video, use [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx). Sample code is available at MSDN site

Answer (score -1):

Example using ReadAllBytes:

```
private byte[] m_cfgBuffer;
m_cfgBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(m_FileName);
StringBuilder PartNbr = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder Version = new StringBuilder();
int i, j;
byte b;
i = 356;    // We know that the cfg file header ends at position 356 (1st hex(80))
b = m_cfgBuffer[i];
while (b != 0x80)   // Scan for 2nd hex(80)
{
    i++;
    b = m_cfgBuffer[i];
}

// Now extract the part number - 6 bytes after hex(80)

m_PartNbrPos = i + 5;
for (j = m_PartNbrPos; j < m_PartNbrPos + 6; j++)
{
   char cP = (char)m_cfgBuffer[j];
   PartNbr.Append(cP);
}
m_PartNbr = PartNbr.ToString();

// Now, extract version number - 6 bytes after part number

m_VersionPos = (m_PartNbrPos + 6) + 6;
for (j = m_VersionPos; j < m_VersionPos + 2; j++)
{
   char cP = (char)m_cfgBuffer[j];
   Version.Append(cP);
}
m_Version = Version.ToString();
```